# IOS: How to load local files in UIWebview eg: .png, .doc, .pdf, etc

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, uiwebview, uiimageview

I need to display local fles like png,pdf,doc into uiwebview. Can anybody help how to load the  local url into webview and display the file in webview..

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *tempUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/0_iphone.png",documentsDirectory];
```

[image]

Comment: that's easy... could you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To load file from your bundle:**

```
  NSString * html = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<img src=\"file://%@\"/>", filename];

 [self.webView loadHTMLString:newhtml  baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

**To load from your document directory:**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.pdf"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `<img>` tag for loading image to `UIWebView`.

```
NSString *imagePath  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImage" ofType:@"png"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",imagePath];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

**EDIT :**

For loading image from document directory, you just need to change the image path in above code, nothing else.

```
NSArray *docPaths            = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *imagePath         = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/yourImage.png"];
```

Comment: am getting file from app directory. its not load image for me.

Comment: If anyone want to load image from local directory to img tags on uiwebview, this is the right answer

Answer (score 2):

check this...

```
UIImage *cameraImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName"];

NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cameraImage);

[self.webview loadData:myData MIMEType:@"image/png" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply load any file in `UIWebView` with passing it as a `NSURL`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your_FIle_name_with_path"]; // Use NSDocumentsDirectory to get local files.
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestURL];
```